# Redirect to non-www and non-https in htaccess

Tags: htaccess, redirects, https, mod-rewrite, no-www

I need to redirect my WordPress blog from `https://www.example.com/blog` to `http://example.com/blog` using the .htaccess file. This is what I have so far:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

However, this only redirects from `https` to `http` but still keeps the `www`. How can I get rid of the `www` and remove the `https` at the same time? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try with these lines only to switch from https to http:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

if not working, look for 301 redirect https to http. This topic is well covered aleady.

To remove the www:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  # Set "protossl" to "s" if we were accessed via https://.  This is used later
  # if you enable "www." stripping or enforcement, in order to ensure that
  # you don't bounce between http and https.
  RewriteRule ^ - [E=protossl]
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
  RewriteRule ^ - [E=protossl:s]

  # To redirect all users to access the site WITHOUT the 'www.' prefix,
  # (http://www.example.com/... will be redirected to http://example.com/...)
  # uncomment the following:
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
   RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

These lines are coming from the Drupal .htaccess but it should work whatever.

Comment: It still has the `www` in the URL.

Comment: I have updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

In the `RewriteRule` you have, you are using `%{HTTP_HOST}` whereas; it should be the matched part from the previous `RewriteCond` statement:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```